# combined mean without population

Tags: mean

I have been given data consisting of means and I would like to calculate the combined mean but I don't have population for none of them.

For example, the average exam score for 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th year students are 68, 72, 69, and 70, respectively. What is the mean score of all students? But in this case I haven't been given the population for each year. Can I calculate the mean score of all students?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't been given the population, then the mean score of all students can only be calculated for one special case, i.e. when the number of students in each year is proportional.

Comment: Can I calculate the sample mean?